# "this._eth.sendTransaction is not a function" when executing method in Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testrpc, react

I'm using react-web3 (which basically gives me a web3 object back) and I'm trying to make my contract work. This is the code I'm using:

```
const web3 = window.web3;
    const contract = new web3.eth.contract(ABI.abi).at("0xdbb05ed3b5acb77cbd2366d037fe051703958dac");
    contract.buyTicket.sendTransaction(3000, {
        from: '0x5c1a92217e456a7eB4a051B567FC751A534991a3',
        value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether')
    });
```

The from is my default address in MetaMask.

My contract:

```
"abi": [
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "restartLottery",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "myid",
          "type": "bytes32"
        },
        {
          "name": "result",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "__callback",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "toggleActive",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "myid",
          "type": "bytes32"
        },
        {
          "name": "result",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "proof",
          "type": "bytes"
        }
      ],
      "name": "__callback",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getTotalPotSize",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "_estimate",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "buyTicket",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": true,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getActiveState",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "bool"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getKrakenPrice",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": true,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "owner",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "_gameId",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "getEstimationPerGame",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "_gameId",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "getBuyersPerGame",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "price",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "estimateAndPayout",
      "type": "event"
    },
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "name": "price",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "priceRetrieved",
      "type": "event"
    }
  ],
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._eth.sendTransaction is not a function
    at c.sendTransaction (inpage.js:8253)
    at test (Landingpage.jsx:22)
    at Landingpage.componentDidMount (Landingpage.jsx:46)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:264
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:263
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:76)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:126)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (ReactMount.js:319)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (ReactMount.js:401)
    at Object.render (ReactMount.js:422)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.js:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 2d91de1…:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 2d91de1…:85)
    at Object.0 (web3Reducer.js:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 2d91de1…:659)
    at ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports (bootstrap 2d91de1…:708)
    at bundle.js:712
```

Any idea?

**Info**
I'm using my contract with testrpc and deploy it there with truffle

Comment: I am not sure what _eth means ,as its is no where in the code snippet you pasted, Generally the sendTranscation  in web3 would be like this  this.eth.sendTransaction,where this is instance of web3.

Comment: what version of web3 are you using? are you sure that `ABI.abi` gives you the ABI as an array?

Comment: Thanks - good hint :) I'm using version  "version": "0.20.1". ABI.abi gives me the correct array

Comment: I think it's because of the `new`, see my edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to call the `sendTransaction` function explicitly, just call the function of your smart-contract like this:

```
contract.buyTicket(3000, {
        from: '0x5c1a92217e456a7eB4a051B567FC751A534991a3',
        gas: 1000000,
        value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether')
    });
```

also don't forget to define the gas-limit

**edit**:
you don't need to instanciate a new object with `new`, web3 should give you the instance of your smart-contract:

```
const contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI.abi).at("0xdbb05ed3b5acb77cbd2366d037fe051703958dac");
```

Comment: Hmmm - error message stays the same